# Should I put sin or cos to represent a sinusoidal signal?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

We were asked in an exercise to create a sinusoidal signal of 0.8 seconds with an amplitude of 1 and frequency equal to 100 Hz sampled at 1000 Hz, but in the answer I found:

```
A=1;fs=100;fe=1000;
te=1/fe;
t=0:te:0.8;
s=A*cos(2*pi*fs*t);
plot(s);
```

And in another exercise: write a script for a sinusoidal signal of amplitude 1 and 200kHz frequency, over a period N = 64, sampled at 150 kHz, the answer was :

```
%Signal
fs=200;N=64;
ts=1/fs;
A=1;
subplot(211);
t=0:0.00001:N*ts;
x=sin(2*pi*t*fs);
plot(t,x);
title('signal sinusoidal');

%Sampling
Fe=input('Fe=');
te=1/Fe;
t1=0:te:N*te;
xe=sin(2*pi*t1*fs);
subplot(212);
stem(t1,xe);
```

I'm so confused. When to put a sin and when to put a cosine? My question is why they put a cosine instead of a sin? Is there some kind of rule behind it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any of those choices qualifies as a sinusoid. Note that

```
cos(2*pi*fs*t)
```

is the same as

```
sin(2*pi*fs*t + pi/2)
```

In general,

```
sin(2*pi*fs*t + phi)
```

is a sinusoid for any choice of `phi` (as would be `cos(2*pi*fs*t + phi)`) . `phi` is the *initial phase* (or simply *phase*) of the sinusoid. To know which `phi` to use you would need an additional condition.

Comment: And of course, the derivative (wrt `x`) of `sin(x)` is `cos(x)`, so if you need two sinusoids related by a derivative (or integral), the math gets a bit easier if you use `sin` for the value and `cos` for the slope